# Socket: process dies after binding a new socket

Tags: c, sockets, ftp, fork

I'm writing an ftp server in C using fork() to handle multiple client. The 
create part and bind part are as follows:

```
//create socket
int createSocket()
{
    int listenfd;
    if ((listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) == -1) 
    {
        printf("Error socket(): %s(%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("socketfd is: %d\n", listenfd);
    return listenfd;
}

int bindSocketToServer(int listenfd, int port)
{
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = port;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    if (bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == -1) 
    {
        printf("Error bind(): %s(%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
        return -1;  
    }
    //It is normal here.
    pirntf("It is still normal here.\n");
    return 1;
}

pasvPort = 30000;
pasvFilefd = createSocket();
while(1)
{
    printf("start.\n");
    if(bindSocketToServer(pasvFilefd, pasvPort) > 0)
    {
        printf("going to break.\n"); 
        break;
    }
    else
        pasvPort += 1;
    printf("error.\n");
}
printf("Listening port%d", pasvPort); //It can be printed.
```

These work fine when I start my server and listen to port 21 in main process. But when I try to handle 'pasv' command and bind a socket to a new port as follows(in another process created by fork()), the process dies and I don't know why.

Edit: That's how I use fork().And in serveOneClient() I handle the 'pasv' command.

```
pid = fork();
if(pid < 0)
{
    printf("Error fork(): %s(%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);           
    continue;
}
else if(pid == 0)
{
    close(listenfd);
    serveOneClient(connfd);
    printf("serving one over.\n");
    close(connfd);
    return 0;
}
else
    close(connfd);
```

Comment: What exactly happens when the process dies?  What error message is displayed?

Comment: Are you waiting the child process in your parent process ? http://www.manpages.info/linux/wait.2.html

Comment: You must ensure that the port is stored in network byte order by using `addr.sin_port = htons(port)`.

Comment: `printf` output is buffered. You need to either add `\n` to your printf string (`printf("OK\n");`) or an explicit call to `flush(stdout)`.

Comment: Your approach to handling PASV seems brittle at best.  You can have only one process listening on a given (address, port) pair at any one time, but you appear to be using only one port to service all PASV transfers.  Since you fork first and attempt to bind the PASV port in the child processes, you'll be unable to handle multiple simultaneous clients in PASV mode.

Comment: Note also that you probably want to set the `SO_REUSEPORT` option on your sockets, or at least on the ones used for your PASV trasfers.  Otherwise, there will be a delay between when you close the listening socket and when you can bind another to the same port.

Comment: It doesn't print anything, just stops replying to that client.

Comment: John: I didn't use `addr.sin_port = htons(port)`, but this function works when I first call it in my main process.

Comment: Add `printf` statements (which include `\n` in the output string) at each step along the way.  That should give you some idea where you're going wrong.

Comment: I use `printf` to look for the problem and the problem seems to occur between "It is still normal here" and "It is going to break". Is it the "return 1" that destroy that process?

Comment: @Owen No, that just returns from the function.  If your code as given above is accurate, I find it hard to believe that the process just dies and nothing prints after that.  You need to step though your code with a debugger to see exactly what's happening.

Comment: The program finally works after I refactored my functions in `server.c`, though I still don't know why... The error just happened and disappeared. But I did learn a lot from above comments.

Comment: The program finally works after I refactored my functions in `server.c`, though I still don't know why... The error just happened and disappeared. But I did learn a lot from above comments.